# How to plot time-series plot with box plot laid on the lines?

Tags: r, time-series, boxplot

I have a dataframe called df. I have 10 replicates for each `sample.id` and using these replicates I want to get the statistics (showing box plots) for the good and bad `Location`. The X-axis should have the `depth` values and the Y axis should have the `observed_otus` values.

I want to get a plot that looks like this

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(sample.id = c("s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", 
"s16", "s1", "s10", "s11", "s13", "s14", "s16", "s1", "s10", 
"s11", "s13", "s14", "s16"), Location = c("GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", 
"GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", 
"GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", 
"GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", 
"GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE", "SALINE", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE"), depth = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", 
"98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", 
"98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", 
"98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", 
"98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", 
"98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "98", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", "196", 
"196", "196", "196"), rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("iter.1", "iter.2", "iter.3", 
"iter.4", "iter.5", "iter.6", "iter.7", "iter.8", "iter.9", "iter.10"
), class = "factor"), observed_otus = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 68L, 58L, 54L, 73L, 61L, 70L, 66L, 52L, 
61L, 71L, 62L, 76L, 74L, 59L, 53L, 73L, 73L, 76L, 70L, 57L, 51L, 
71L, 59L, 70L, 73L, 57L, 57L, 75L, 70L, 63L, 74L, 61L, 56L, 74L, 
66L, 66L, 74L, 56L, 55L, 72L, 60L, 73L, 76L, 55L, 63L, 68L, 64L, 
71L, 79L, 59L, 56L, 72L, 58L, 61L, 73L, 56L, 56L, 70L, 65L, 69L, 
122L, 79L, 82L, 118L, 95L, 117L, 117L, 82L, 82L, 118L, 97L, 100L, 
115L, 86L, 77L, 109L, 96L, 115L, 120L, 76L, 84L, 117L, 102L, 
116L, 110L, 87L, 81L, 117L, 91L, 115L, 121L, 79L, 79L, 127L, 
96L, 114L, 117L, 78L, 86L, 109L, 96L, 114L, 113L, 85L, 70L, 111L, 
100L, 107L, 117L, 86L, 79L, 118L, 104L, 117L, 111L, 75L, 83L, 
110L, 95L, 110L)), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to plot boxplots

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot`-solution to your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% mutate_at("depth",factor,unique(sort(as.numeric(.$depth)))) #converting the depth values to factor and order

ggplot(df, aes(x=depth, y=observed_otus,color=Location)) + #initialize ggplot
geom_boxplot(position="identity") +  #initialize boxplot
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=Location))  + #add mean line
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point") # add mean points
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it does not separate GOOD and SALINE samples (i.e, Location).

Comment: I've updated the solution. Unfortunately your example dataset overlaps here which leads to a bit of an ugly visualization and I can't figure out how to get the `mean`points and lines working with dodging boxes at the moment

Comment: Or use the `fill` `df %>% mutate(depth = paste0("A", depth)) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = depth, y = observed_otus, fill = Location)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=Location)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")`

Comment: @akrun: This works as well (albeit not ordered, but I already showed him), but does not solve the "problem" that the means of the groups are now located in the middle of the dodged boxes. I can't figure out an easy fix for that on the spot.

Comment: @akrun How do you set the colors of lines based on Location?

Comment: @MAPK add the `color` parameter `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=Location, color = Location))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in which the boxes are plotted to the scale of the depth.  I also added a slight offset to prevent the boxes from completely overlapping.

```
#convert depth to numeric 
 df$depth<- as.numeric(df$depth)

library(ggplot2)
g<-ggplot(df, aes(x=depth, y=observed_otus, color=Location)) +
  geom_boxplot(data=df[df$Location =="GOOD",], aes(x=depth-1, y=observed_otus, group=depth), width=1.5) +
  geom_boxplot(data=df[df$Location =="SALINE",], aes(x=depth+1, y=observed_otus, group=depth),  color="blue", width=1.5) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=Location, color=Location))  + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(group=Location)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue"))
print(g)
```

[image]